# why cloud funtion in node js doesnt deploy propely

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

here iam using a cloud functions to create users i am using a express module when i try to deploy this code it deploying to cloud funtions with message that Error : Funtions did not deploy properly

```
const express = require('express');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceaccount = require('./ServiceAccountKey.json');

const app = express();

admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceaccount)
});


app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
if(req.method!== 'POST'){
    res.status(400).send("what are u trying baby");
    return;
}
admin.auth().createUser({
    email:req.body.email,
    password: req.body.pass,
}).then(function(userRecord){
    res.send({'uid': userRecord.uid});
    return;
}).catch(function(error){
    res.send({'error': 'Try COrrect one baby'});
    return;
});
return;
});
exports.register = funtions.Https.onRequest(app);
```

when i add this at end

```
module.exports = {
app
}
```

it showing funtion deployed but its not showing in cloud functions dashboard

what wrong am i doing here

here is the error what ima getting i cnat get whAT THE error is

```
⚠  functions[register(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js     can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/index.js:1:79)
at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    register
```

Answer (score 0):

You code never uses the `firebase-functions` modules to declare a Cloud Function.  Your `functions` variable is going unused.  You can't just export any function an expect it to run - it has to be built by the SDK.

If you have an express app to deploy, you need to export it via an HTTP type function:

```
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: iam sorry i forgot to add that in question i edited my question i have already included it in my code also a same problem

Comment: Why are you also trying to export `app` directly, though?  Maybe you should edit the question and include the entire file contents rather than trying to break it up.

Comment: i dont know i should keep that module.export r not because i dont y it is for i saw some documentation and i tried is it needed

Comment: i tried adding madule.export{app} to my code it suffcessfully deployed  but its not showing in cloud functions dashboard,when i removed it tried it gives error that functions didn't deploy properly but it deployed and showing in dashboard and got url but what that error mean

Comment: If the dashboard doesn't snow what you expect, you should contact Firebase support directly.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: is there any mistake in code i will edit my quetion and add the error msg also

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you need to change the endpoint of the url. Don't just put '/'. Maybe like '/user/create'.

```
app.post('/user/create',(req,res)=>{
  if(req.method!== 'POST'){
    res.status(400).send("what are u trying baby");
    return;
  }
  admin.auth().createUser({
    email:req.body.email,
    password: req.body.pass,
  }).then(function(userRecord){
     res.send({'uid': userRecord.uid});
     return;
  }).catch(function(error){
    res.send({'error': 'Try COrrect one baby'});
    return;
  });
  return;
});

exports.register = funtions.Https.onRequest(app);
```

And in your `firebase.json` you should rewrite the url :

```
{
  "functions": {
       ...
   },
  "hosting": {
     "public": "public",
     "rewrites": [
        { 
          "source": "/user/create",
          "function": "register" 
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

For more explanation, you can follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8).